# Comparar Hash de dois arquivos em Python

Tags: python, hash

Preciso comparar o hash dos arquivos a.txt e b.txt usando uma biblioteca nativa do python3.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
import hashlib

file_0 = 'a.txt'
file_1 = 'b.txt'

hash_0 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
hash_0.update(file_0)
hash_1 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
hash_1.update(file_1)

assert hash_0 != hash_1, f'O arquivo: {file_0} é diferente do arquivo: {file_1} '
```

Mas ocorreu o seguinte erro:

**TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing**

---

Obs: Antes de editar cometi o erro de por duas variáveis file_0. No projeto estava correto.

Comment: Você precisa comparar os conteúdos dos arquivos ou os nomes deles apenas? Da forma que está fazendo você comparará apenas os nomes. O método `update` aceita apenas *bytes-like* como parâmetro, então precisará codificar a sua *string* com o método `encode`.

Comment: Preciso comparar o conteúdo do arquivo. Vou continuar pesquisando e encontrar como comparo o conteúdo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro - você está comparando os nomes dos arquivos - a chamada a `update` nas classes da Hashlib não abre arquivos sozinha - ela espera objetos do tipo "bytes" (e esse é o motivo da mensagem de erro, você esta passando texto) - mas mesmo que você ponha o prefixo `b'` nessas strings de nome, ou use `.encode()` nas mesmas, vai continuar fazendo o hash só do nome dos arquivos. (Outro erro: você usou duas vezes o mesmo nome de variável - *se estivesse abrindo os arquivos*, iria estar comparando o arquivo "b.txt" com ele mesmo)

Para ver o hash do conteúdo dos arquivos faça:

```
import hashlib

file_0 = 'a.txt'
file_1 = 'b.txt'

hash_0 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
hash_0.update(open(file_0, 'rb').read())

hash_1 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
hash_1.update(open(file_1, 'rb').read())

if hash_0.digest() != hash_1.digest():
    print(f'O arquivo: {file_0} é diferente do arquivo: {file_1} ')
```

(você também estava usando o `assert` de forma errada. Evite usar o  `assert` em código mesmo - e reserve esse comando para testes.
Apesar de parecer um encurtamento de um  `if` seguido de um  `raise` em alguns lugares, ele é um teste que é **desabilitado** dependendo dos parâmetros com que o runtime do Python é executado - então, tem muito desenvolvedor aí colocando `assert` em código de produção que mais dia menos dia pode se encrencar, com um teste que não é feito, por conta de uma configuração aparentemente inócua alterada em outro lugar)

Comment: Perdoe a ignorância, mas não seria melhor os arquivos serem abertos para leitura ao invés de escrita? Usando `rb` ao invés de `wb`?

Comment: Isso -deveria ter sido "rb" - está errado aí - vou alterar.

Answer (score 5):

Para comparar usando `hashlib` pode ser feito assim:

```
import hashlib

def open_txt(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return "".join(f.read())

file_1 = 'a.txt'
file_2 = 'b.txt'
text_1 = open_txt(file_1)
text_2 = open_txt(file_2)

def compare(text_1, text_2):
    hash_1 = hashlib.md5()
    hash_1.update(text_1.encode('utf-8'))
    hash_1 = hash_1.hexdigest()

    hash_2 = hashlib.md5()
    hash_2.update(text_2.encode('utf-8'))
    hash_2 = hash_2.hexdigest()

    assert hash_1 == hash_2, f'O arquivo: {file_1} é diferente do arquivo: {file_2} '


compare(text_1, text_2)
```

Porém acho mais prático e rápido usar `filecmp` que compara byte a byte.

```
import filecmp
filecmp.cmp('a.txt', 'b.txt')
```